# No colour when I render model I dowloaded from the internet

Tags: rendering

I've seen an intro template online in youtube and just want to change the text to someone's name.
I've downloaded this .blend template (it also included a .aep file, .jsx file and an mp3.
I opened the .blend in Blender 2.90.1
Once opened, it shows the original sequence from the downloaded youtube video, but there's no colour. (ie it's black text on a grey background)
I selected and tabbed the "front" and "back" of the original word and replaced this with the new name.
Now the tutorials I see online differ between some saying animate straight into a movie file and others saying to create PNGs.
What I have done is create 650 PNGs in a folder.
These PNGs are all black images on a white background so I'm not sure if I've not done something correct to fill in all of the PNGs with the correct colours.
If I now go to the Video Editing screen, I can select the 650 PNGs and then in rendering output choose FFMPEG using MPEG4 with AAC audio.
Once this has rendered, I get a MP4 file but the whole thing is black.
I do hear the mp3 music track that was in the original download.
Can you let me know how I can actually have the colour version like the original youtube video, and what am I doing wrong in terms of rendering it?

I feel so sure that it's one of those obvious things, but for someone new to looking at Blender there seems so much to it!

On opening the .blend template, Blender shows this[image]

The original looks like this
[image]

But in material view it's like this:
[image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot pls

Comment: Here's what Blender shows as soon as I open the .blend file:

Comment: Please also make sure you're using the same Blender version that the tutorial is using. Of course, providing a link to the tutorial would help.

Comment: Added the image in the original post as requested

Comment: With regards a tutorial, there wasn't anything on the youtube video. It showed 10 intor videos with links to them so that they could be downloaded and amended as appropriate. Thanks

Comment: So I think the problem is that I also need After Effects to be able to do this. There seems to be lots of videos just saying amend this Blender video/template and doesn't mention any other requirements. If that's the case, as I only wanted to make a small video, then I guess buying After Effects isn't really worth it. Thanks for the replies. I told you I was new to this !! :)

Comment: you are in solid view, press z and go to material or rendered view

Comment: thanks but even in either material or rendered, it still shows with no colours. I'll post screen shots including that of the actual original video

Comment: The first thing I'd suspect is that there aren't any lights in the template.  If that's the case, and the materials used aren't emissive, you'll get a black render-- same as taking a photograph without a flash in a dark cave.  You'll want to look at either lighting or materials for your file.

Comment: ok thanks - I was rather hoping that by using a template that all these things would be setup as soon as you opened it, but I guess I've just been too naive to think it would be that simple!! No matter, thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried  actually rendering it(maybe they are using compositing tricks)

Comment: It sounds like you are rendering an animated matte... what is in the after effects file you have as well?

Comment: in response to Uncommon Blend: sorry I don't have After Effects, so unable to say what's in the file. I do appreciate your help though. I was hoping to just pick a decent intro blend file (for a video montage), change the text of the name and then use it in my video. It seems that these videos on youtube for intro templates need After Effects as well, which I was hoping to avoid as just wanted a 10 second video clip. I guess I'll try and find something else for now. thks